# create a mongodb module for user to book any of the room, only on working days, just the time slot of 30 minute, from 9am to 9pm

Tags: reactjs, express, mongodb-query, mern

I am a new developer, i am working on a website. user can select any room, based on day(except saturday and sunday) and book time slot of 30 minutes, from 9am to 9pm.(like 9am, 9:30am,10am etc). user can book any number of time slot and any of the available room. I am so stucked on booking model.

the user schema is:->

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    email :  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },

    room: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Room", required: true }],
})
```

and Room model is:->

```
const RoomSchema = new Schema({
    imageUrl : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    description:  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    }
})
```

but what should be my booking model would be.
i coded a demo model.
which is------------------------>

```
`const roomBooking = new mongoose.Schema({
    room:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Room',
        required:true
    },
    year:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    month:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    day:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }
})`
```

someone help me out of this module struggle.